# add new row to numpy using realtime reading

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, raspberry-pi3

I am using a microstacknode accelerometer and intend to save it into csv file.

```
while True:
    numpy.loadtxt('foo.csv', delimiter=",")
    raw = accelerometer.get_xyz(raw=True)
    g = accelerometer.get_xyz()
    ms = accelerometer.get_xyz_ms2()
    a = numpy.asarray([[raw['x'],raw['y'],raw['z']]])
    numpy.savetxt("foo.csv",a,delimiter=",",newline="\n")
```

However, the saving is only done on 1 line. Any help given? Still quite a noobie on python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy is not the best solution for this type of things.
This should do what you intend:

```
while True:
    raw = accelerometer.get_xyz(raw=True)
    fobj = open('foo.csv', 'a')
    fobj.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(raw['x'], raw['y'], raw['z']))
    fobj.close()
```

Here `fobj = open('foo.csv', 'a')` opens the file in append mode. So if the file already exists, the next writing will go to the end of file, keeping the data in the file.
Let's have look at your code. This line:

```
numpy.loadtxt('foo.csv', delimiter=",")
```

reads the whole file but doe not do anything with the at it read, because you don't assign to a variable. You would need to do something like this:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt('foo.csv', delimiter=",")
```

This line:

```
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv",a,delimiter=",",newline="\n")
```

Creates a new file with the name `foo.csv` overwriting the existing one. Therefore, you see only one line, the last one written.

This should do the same but dos not open and close the file all the time:

```
with open('foo.csv', 'a') as fobj:
    while True:
        raw = accelerometer.get_xyz(raw=True)
        fobj.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(raw['x'], raw['y'], raw['z']))
```

The `with open()` opens the file with the promise to close it even in case of an exception. For example, if you break out of the `while True` loop with `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: Thanks dude. Appreciated it!